# where does python println when running in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I got this api running in python and can get it to update a .csv file but when I just have it print stocks I have no idea where it is outputting this data. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import os
import time

# loop that checks stock prices every 20 seconds and adds them to the file
while 1:
    # sometimes this program gives me socket errors so if it does skip this itteration of the loop
    try:
        stocks = urllib.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=JPM+C&f=snl1c6').read()
    except IOError:
        print ("error reading the socket")
        time.sleep(120) #if we don't sleep here loop constently retrys with no delay
        continue
    print stocks
```

Comment: To format it as code, add 4 spaces extra before each line of code (press edit on your post to see how it was done).

Answer (score 2):

It works. There should be no issue.

```
>>> stocks = urllib.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=JPM+C&f=snl1c6').read()
>>> print stocks
"JPM","JP Morgan Chase &",33.175,"+0.955"
"C","Citigroup, Inc. N",28.87,"+1.12"
```

Why do you want to do that in a loop? and if it succeeds, you are immediately making another query.

Answer (score 0):

```
python yourprogram.py >> outfile
```

In your comments you say you want the output to go to a file.  This will continually append to outfile

Answer (score 0):

By default it prints to `sys.stdout`. Check the documentation for [`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print).